# Can I assign multiple bindings to a MonoDevelop command?

Tags: monodevelop, key-bindings

I'm using `MonoDevelop-Unity` `4.0.1`, can I assign to it multiple keybindings to a single command?

In case it matters:

- the command would be `Toggle All Folds`
- the OS is `OSX 10.8`